# Create a flavor that extends another flavor using gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I have an Android application that has two flavors, free and premium. I would like to create another flavor, flavorExt, that is based on the free flavor but has some additional functionality. I have done this using the sourceSets option in gradle, like the following:

```
   sourceSets {
        freeExt {
            java.srcDirs = sourceSets.free.java.srcDirs
            res.srcDirs = sourceSets.free.res.srcDirs
            resources.srcDirs = sourceSets.free.resources.srcDirs
        }
    }
```

Now I would like to add some additional functionality to the freeExt flavor but I do not know if this is possible and if so, how it can be done. I have created the flavor source folder as app/src/freeExt/java/... and added the necessary files in it. I also added the following line in the sourceSets entry in gradle without success:

```
java.srcDirs = sourceSets.free.java.srcDirs
```

Is what I am trying to do possible in gradle? If so, how can it be done?

Comment: There are some use cases where this is useful, but for most cases if you are doing so much in the buildFlavor configuration that you need to extend it, you may be using it for more than it is intended for. If you really need to use it though, as @Tanis.7x stated, dimensions are going to be your best option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend creating a second flavor dimension for the added functionality. [You can find the documentation on multiple flavor dimensions here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#flavor-dimensions).

Your build.gradle would look something like this:

```
android {

    flavorDimensions "tier", "extras"

    productFlavors {
        free {
          dimension "tier"
          ...
        }

        full {
          dimension "tier"
          ...
        }

        withExtras {
          dimension "extras"
          ...
        }

        noExtras {
          dimension "extras"
          ...
        }
    }
}
```

The Android Gradle Plugin will generate variants using the cross-product of each flavor in each dimension. Thus you will end up with a `freeWithExtras`, `freeNoExtras`, `fullWithExtras` and `fullNoExtras`. You don't necessarily need to release all four variants.

Comment: The `withExtras` flavor in this approach isn't "based on" the free flavor, but all of the code for both the `free` flavor and the `withExtras` will be included in the `freeWithExtras` variant. My suggestion is basically to not worry about *extending* an existing flavor and instead abstract away the extra content into a new flavor.